# How to view a demo on Github?

Tags: github

[I want to view the demo hosted here on Github](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/tree/master/demo).

https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/tree/master/demo

(By *view*, I mean see the HTML files rendered in my browser.)

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can view it by downloading the repo files to your computer and running it in your local browser by opening the files with your preferred browser.

Comment: But *how* do I run it in a local browser? For example, right clicking the file `demo/index.html` and open with Chrome (for example) doesn't work. Do I need to fire up a local server or something? What's the procedure?

Comment: Yes, that is the right way to do it for any given HTML files, by opening the file with a browser.
However, when it comes to HTML, the browser can render it only if the file is syntactically correct. 

In this case, I believe there is a problem with the HTML files, which is beyond the scope of this question's solution.

Answer (score -1):

u can clone or download this repo and install Web Server for Chrome = https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb to view the demo